# Declare table name to use in different "From"-statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I wan´t to create two different temp tables from a set of table pairs which has the same table name in at least two different databases. All in all I have 4 different table pairs and that is the reason why I try to declare a variable for it, so I only have to change the table name in the top of the program.

When I try to declare a variable for the use in a "From"-statement, but cannot get the code to work. I have read up a bit on dynamic programming but don´t really understand how to use it in this context.

```
DECLARE @table char(20);
SET @table = 'Table_1';

SELECT a.*
into #temp1
FROM [DB_1].[Schema].@table a  

select a.*
into #temp2
FROM [DB_2].[Schema].@table a
```

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Just repeat the code 4 times.  The code is not very long and you are putting the results into different temporary tables.  Dynamic programming would just make the code more confusing for this purpose.

Comment: You're trying to use a *string* (variable) where SQL Server expects a *name*. You should realise that those two things are *not* the same thing. If you have multiple tables with identical structures, such that the above code even makes sense, it's usually an indication that the data modelling has gone wrong and there should be a *single* table with additional columns containing the *data* currently embedded in object *names* (where, note, they're not as easily queryable - quite possibly the problem you're now trying to work around)

Comment: Although not the best solution here, [read this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for an understanding of dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your replys! The full code is longer, and the final list of table pairs may grow and span more than just two databases. That´s why I was looking in to dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just used Adventure works sample database as sample database ,please use this sql script it will meets your expected result

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableList')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TableList

CREATE TABLE #TableList(
            Id INT IDENTITY,
            TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
            TABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(100),
            TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(100),
            TempTableNAme VARCHAR(100)
            )
INSERT INTO #TableList
            (TABLE_NAME,
            TABLE_CATALOG,
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            TempTableNAme
            )

SELECT  TABLE_NAME ,
        TABLE_CATALOG ,
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        '#Temp'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS TempTableNAme
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
ORDER BY 1

DECLARE @MaxID INT,
        @MinID INT,
        @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @GetTABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
        @GetTABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(100),
        @GetTABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(100),
        @GetTempTableNAme VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @MaxID=Max(Id),@MinID=Min(Id)
FROM #TableList

WHILE @MinID<=@MaxID
BEGIN
SELECT @GetTABLE_NAME= TABLE_NAME ,
       @GetTABLE_CATALOG =TABLE_CATALOG,
       @GetTABLE_SCHEMA=TABLE_SCHEMA,
       @GetTempTableNAme=TempTableNAme
FROM #TableList WHERE Id = @MinID

SET @Sql='SELECT * INTO '+@GetTempTableNAme+'_'+@GetTABLE_NAME+' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@GetTABLE_CATALOG) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(@GetTABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+ QUOTENAME(@GetTABLE_NAME)
--EXEC (@Sql)
PRINT @Sql
SET @MinID=@MinID+1
END
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Dynamic SQL for this purpose:

```
DECLARE @table char(20);
SET @table = 'Table_1';

SET @SQL = 'SELECT a.* into #temp1 FROM [DB_1].[Schema].' + @table + 'a'  

SET @SQL2 = 'select a.* into #temp2 FROM [DB_2].[Schema].' + @table + 'a'
EXEC(@SQL);
EXEC(@SQL2);
```

Comment: Try doing a `SELECT * FROM #temp1` after inserting into it.